# Magento 2: Initialize calendar widget inside payment uiComponent

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, payment-gateway, calendar

I am working on a Payment Gateway and I have to work with the customer's date of birth with a certain payment option.

To get this, I want to load the calendar widget on a text input field (since date of birth is not required for all shops, I have to to it this way).

My component extends an 'abstract' component, which extends 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default':

**Abstract renderer which serves as 'parent' (abstract.js)**:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Modulename_Gateway/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators'
    ],
    function ($, Component, placeOrderAction, additionalValidators) {
        return Component.extend({
            ...
        });
    }
);
```

**Renderer for the given payment method (directdebitsecured.js)**:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Modulename_Gateway/js/view/payment/method-renderer/abstract',
        'Modulename_Gateway/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'mage/calendar'
    ],
    function ($, Component, placeOrderAction, urlBuilder, storage, additionalValidators, customer, quote) {
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {},
            initialize: function() {},
        });
    }
);
```

Of course, defaults and initialize function are not empty.
The js/action/place-order file contains logic for the order placement.

The HTML template file is defined in the defaults object of my directdebitsecured component:

```
defaults: {
    template: 'Modulename_Gateway/payment/modulename-directdebit-secured-form',
    birthdate: ''
},
```

Inside that file I want to load the calendar widget, but I have no success.
I've tried several ways:

**Binding it to my input text field**

- via data-mage-init='{"calendar": {}}' *(just nothing happens)*
- data-bind="mageInit: {'calendar': {}}" *(throws an error in requireJs)*

**Calling it directly**

- jQuery('#idOfMyInputField').calendar({}); *(just nothing happens)*

**Calling it with requireJs inside of the HTML template**

```
require(["jquery","mage/calendar"], function($){
    $("#birthdate").calendar({
        showTime: false,
        //dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

**Calling it inside of my compoent, which defines $ for jQuery**

- $('#idOfMyInputField').calendar({}); *(just nothing happens)*

---

Anyone has a idea, why none of these ways is working?

Btw, calling

`jQuery('#birthdate').calendar({});`

in the console when the page is loaded works without problems.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Could someone help on same?

Comment: try this one: defaults: {
 template: {
  name: 'Modulename_Gateway/payment/modulename-directdebit-secured-form',
  afterRender: function() {
   $("#birthdate").calendar({
    showTime: false,
    //dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
   });
  }
 },
 birthdate: ''
},

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the require method inside a JS file rather than the template, I don't see why this wouldn't work providing you've added the `x-magento-init` tag correctly and cleared all caches and `var/view_preprocessed`, `pub/static/frontend` and `pub/static/_requirejs`.

```
require(["jquery","mage/calendar"], function($){
    $("#birthdate").calendar({
        showTime: false,
        //dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```